# ShelllJS exec returning null for every command -- Atom Package Development

Tags: node.js, atom-editor, shelljs

I am creating an Atom package and trying to incorporate a [ShellJS](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) command. I want to use the `exec()` commmand, and it's returning null everytime, for every command.

```
shelljs = require 'shelljs/global'

console.log exec('which git').code // returns null
console.log which 'git' // returns the correct path
```

why?

Comment: I tried `console.log(exec('which git').code);` and it works well. Shelljs version is 0.7.4. Maybe this issue has been fixed in shelljs.

Answer (score 0):

> console.log exec('which git').code // returns null

This tries to run an external executable named `which` but there's no such program. `which` is a shell built-in command, not a standalone program, so it fails.

> console.log which 'git' // returns the correct path

This uses the shelljs `which` function, which is a direct analog to the same command in a shell, so it works.